# Use loading animation onlick if inputs are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, button

I have page with inputs and selections. Here is my loading animation which is working on page loading, but I want to set it on button click and make it work only if inputs are filled. I need it because user should confirm rules, check written information and on submit it sends mail which takes from 3-15seconds. i need to fill this pause with loading gif

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  // Animate loader off screen
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
 });
```

```css
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 background: url(path-to-gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>

<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
```

Comment: And what have you tried yourself to check if the inputs are filled?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Added js code to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by Jquery. There are much more easy way. Here is way to check validations of inputs depends on your inputs requirments and on success show animation:

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});


$('#My-Button').on('click', function() {
  if ($("#My-Form").valid()) {
    $("#My-Form")[0].submit();
    $('#My-Animation').show();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ok6byo68/1/

```js
$('#formz').submit(function(event) {
  $('#load').show();
    var valid = true;
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
     if(!$(this).val()){
       valid = false;
      }
    })
    if(!valid) {
       event.preventDefault();
        console.log('All fields are required!');
        setTimeout(function(){
     $('#load').hide();
        },1000);
        return;
    }
});
```

```css
#load{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    background: url("https://www.creditmutuel.fr/cmne/fr/banques/webservices/nswr/images/loading.gif") no-repeat center center rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formz" id="formz" >

<input type="text"  name="first" >

<input type="text"   name="second" >

<input type="text" name="third"   >

<button type="submit" id="button" class = 'button' >Done</button>

</form>
<div id="load" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I also can do this, but I need to make it work only if all inputs are filled. In your and mine situation it works if press button and I do not need it.

Comment: @Orik3ll0 - You can make form submit without pressing the button. [Check here](https://jsfiddle.net/ok6byo68/2/)

Comment: Problem is I must press the button, cause user should submit rules and check written information one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that the following will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    beforeSend : function(xhr, opts){
        //show loading gif
        $('#load').show(); 
    },
    success: function(){
         //hide loading gif
                $('#load').hide(); 
    }
});
```

}

});

Comment: Thank you for help, but I do not see in this code check for empty inputs. I need it work only if all inputes are filled

Comment: You can make <input type="text" name="usrname" required> all the input fields as required.